# Rename files based on their created time + date

Tags: python

I've just started learning Python and trying to understand what's wrong with the code below.

For the test purpose there are 50 images that I want to rename as `Hour.Minute.Second_Year_Month_Day.jpg`. The code below executes, but I'm getting the current time and date as file name, not the creation date of the images.

What am I missing? I was reading that `getctime` is for Windows and for Mac `birthtime`, or I'm talking nonsense *(Bringing this up since I'm on a Mac)* ?

```
directory = './'
extensions = (['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png']);

filelist = os.listdir( directory )

newfilesDictionary = {}

count = 0

for file in filelist:
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
    if ( extension in extensions ):
        create_time = os.path.getctime( file )
        format_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( create_time )
        format_time_string = format_time.strftime("%H.%M.%S_%Y-%m-%d")
        newfile = format_time_string + extension; 

        if ( newfile in newfilesDictionary.keys() ):
            index = newfilesDictionary[newfile] + 1;
            newfilesDictionary[newfile] = index; 
            newfile = format_time_string + '-' + str(index) + extension;
        else:
            newfilesDictionary[newfile] = 0; 

        os.rename( file, newfile );
        count = count + 1
        print( file.rjust(35) + '    =>    ' + newfile.ljust(35) )


print( 'All done. ' + str(count) + ' files are renamed. ')
```

Comment: The parenthesis in the if-statements are redundant and there is no need for semicolons in Python code

Answer (score 1):

Under MacOS, you should try `st_birthtime`:

```
os.stat(file).st_birthtime
```

Note that your current code works as expected on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**RECTIFIED CODE:-**

```
import os
import datetime

directory = r'Dir_path'
extensions = (['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png']);

filelist = os.listdir( directory )

newfilesDictionary = {}

count = 0

for file in filelist:
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
    if ( extension in extensions ):
        create_time = os.path.getctime( os.path.join(directory, file) )
        format_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( create_time )
        format_time_string = format_time.strftime("%H.%M.%S_%Y-%m-%d")
        newfile = format_time_string + extension;

        if ( newfile in newfilesDictionary.keys() ):
            index = newfilesDictionary[newfile] + 1;
            newfilesDictionary[newfile] = index;
            newfile = format_time_string + '-' + str(index) + extension;
        else:
            newfilesDictionary[newfile] = 0;

        os.rename( os.path.join(directory, file), os.path.join(directory, newfile))
        count = count + 1
        print( file.rjust(35) + '    =>    ' + newfile.ljust(35) )


print( 'All done. ' + str(count) + ' files are renamed. ')
```

Your code run's fine of Windows OS, just did a little improvement by adding `os.path.join()` to make it a lot more flexible while dealing with files. If you're on Mac, then try using `os.stat(file).st_birthtime` instead of `os.path.getctime()`.

**SUGGESTED IMPROVEMENTS:-**

- The Timestamp structure that you are using is not the best, as
  Timestamps are generally made in descending order of time duration
  i.e Year > Month > Day > Hour > Minutes > Seconds.  This timestamp
  standard **(ISO 8601)** is commonly used.
- Your should pass the extension of the file via `lower()` to make the
  extension all lowercase. As you code won't be able to deal with Image
  files with extension `.JPG` or `.PNG`.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you!